# How to use ion view in ionic 2

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Initially i have used in ionic 1 to use the footer after the `<ion-content>` and befoew .But in new ionic 2 i dont see any `<ion-view>` is availble.

Because my requirement is after `<ion-content>` i need to have some two button at bottom of screen. It might be a fotter. So how can i use thos below ionic 1 code to make the footer button in **ionic 2** ??

```
 <div class="bar bar-footer bar-clear footer-button btnpadding" style="margin-bottom: 6px;padding-right: 6px; height: 8%;padding-top: 3px;">

               <div class="button-bar font-color">
                  <button class="button button-outline" style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;border: none;color: #696969;background-color: #fff"  ng-click="LoginButtontap()">LOG IN</button>
                  <button class="button button-dark button-outline" style="margin-bottom: 5px;
                      margin-right: 5px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;border: none;color: #fff">SIGN UP</button> 
              </div> 

          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic 2 the basic page template follow this structure:

```html
<ion-header>
  <!-- PAGE HEADER CODE HERE -->
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <!-- PAGE CONTENT CODE HERE -->
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <!-- FOOTER CODE HERE -->
   <ion-button outline style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;border: none;color: #696969;background-color: #fff"  (click)="LoginButtontap()">LOG IN</ion-button>
   <ion-button outline color="dark" style="margin-bottom: 5px;
                      margin-right: 5px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;border: none;color: #fff">SIGN UP</ion-button> 
</ion-footer>
```

so all you have to do is to put your buttons inside the `<ion-footer>` element. See also the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/)